# Create directory and recursively copy files with differing access rights using Puppet

Tags: puppet

I would like to create/ensure a directory exists and recursively copy many files to it using native Puppet methods if possible. The file modes are same for all files but differ from the directory.

I am using Puppet6 version 6.10.0 on CentOS 6.10

This code will create/ensure my directory exists and copy all the files to it but sets the access rights and ownership exactly the same.

```
file { "/opt/dir1":
  ensure  => "directory",
  owner   => "user1",
  group   => "root",
  mode    => "0700",
  recurse => true,
  source  => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/dir1",
}
```

What I get:

```
ls -la /opt/dir1"
drwx------ 2 user1 root 4096 Sep 23 20:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user1 root 4096 Oct  6 15:20 ..
-rwx------ 1 user1 root   72 Oct  5 17:15 file1
```

What I want:

```
ls -la /opt/dir1"
drwx------ 2 user1 root 4096 Sep 23 20:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user1 root 4096 Oct  6 15:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 root   72 Oct  5 17:15 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to manage the permissions and mode in the source you can use this parameter [`source_permissions => use`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-source_permissions). Note, depending on your version you may get a deprecated warning:

```
Warning: The `source_permissions` parameter is deprecated. Explicitly set `owner`, `group`, and `mode`.

file { "/opt/dir1":
  ensure            => "directory",
  owner             => "user1",
  group             => "root",
  source_permissions => "use",
  recurse           => true,
  source            => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/dir1",
}
```

This would allow you do manage the mode in the `source` but still override the owner and group.  you could also drop the owner and group params above and manage them in the source as well.  However I'm not sure how this works if you have windows clients and a linux puppet master, or a missmatch in users/groups on the master vs agent

Comment: This works good for the files but the directory needs to be 0700 not 0755 which is being set now without a 'mode' parameter.

Comment: Even if the source dir has mode `0700`?

Comment: This is a little embarrassing, it does work as expected! was a crazy day yesterday when I tested this. It is an issue though for me in that I had to make the owner puppet so it can be seen by puppet. Now I can't make changes as myself. Not sure how other shops are set up, a question for another day. Another caveat with this is the "deprecated" warning I get with the 'source_permissions' parameter. Anyhoo this does kind of answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Puppet `file` resource can't set different modes for the apex directory and its files when using `recurse`. https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/file.html#file-attribute-mode

Would you be able to use an [`archive` resource](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/archive) instead? With an `archive` resource, you can specify a `tar` file as the source, and the permissions will be set following those in the `tar` file.